# How to remove unused physical volume from LVM?

Tags: centos, hard-disk, volume

I have two pv's under a vg:

[image]

and I want to remove unknown device physical volume.

I've tried this but does not remove it:

```
vgreduce --removemissing --force vg_centos6
```

How can I remove that pv?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the physical extents over to some other source before starting your `vgreduce` action to physically (or virtually) remove the device. The following is documented on RedHat's  customer portal, so it should work with most versions of LVM currently being utilized.

Check to make sure you have room

```
root# pvs -o+pv_used
PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  Used
/dev/sda1  myvg lvm2 a-   17.15G 12.15G  5.00G
/dev/sdb1  myvg lvm2 a-   17.15G 12.15G  5.00G
```

Move data to new physical volume

```
root# pvmove /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: Moved: 2.0%
...
```

Check again to make sure everything copied over

```
root# pvs -o+pv_used
PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree  Used
/dev/sda1  myvg lvm2 a-   17.15G  7.15G 10.00G
/dev/sdb1  myvg lvm2 a-   17.15G 17.15G     0
```

Shrink the volume group

```
# vgreduce myvg /dev/sdb1
Removed "/dev/sdb1" from volume group "myvg"
```

Remove the physical (or virtual) disk

Comment: I have no free space in any pvs.

Comment: Then you either have to free up space to move those physical extents, add another disk or do something else to alleviate the storage issue before you can remove it.

Comment: my pv name is unknown device. pvmove unknown device not even working.

Comment: If you have no free space to move it to, it will not work. You have to solve the storage issue first. Additionally, you seem to have removed this physical volume from the LVM configuration, somehow, and will need to recover your original LVM configuration in order to process this out. Good luck.